# can not add item to NSMutableDictionary in swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, nsmutabledictionary

I want to add the following items to a NSMutableDictionary but I get the following error

```
could not find an overload for setObject that accepts the following arguments


import Security

var returnDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()

returnDictionary.setObject(anObject: kSecClassGenericPassword, forKey: kSecClass)
```

when I browse to security.h file, the attributes are shown to be declared as below:

```
var kSecClass: Unmanaged<AnyObject>!
var kSecClassGenericPassword: Unmanaged<AnyObject>!
```

Comment: You cannot work with an Unmanaged. You _must_ immediately send it `takeRetained` or `takeUnretained` before you can do anything with it.

Comment: Also may I recommend that you not attempt to work directly with an NSMutableDictionary in Swift. Use a Swift dictionary and pass it to Objective-C when you're finished with it.

Comment: thank you matt, I want to use these to set a password in the keychain, I assumed that kSecClass should be passed in as key for kSecClassGenericPassword to KeyChain? is that not the case?

Comment: OK, I see what you mean; you can't use an AnyObject as a key in a Swift dictionary. Sorry about that.

Comment: so, does that mean I have to use an string as key for kSecClassGenericPassword? would I still be able to use the KeyChain if i did it this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to pass the strings directly, i.e. `"class"` and `"genp"`. You might want to file a bug report about this; Apple needs to provide more Swift-friendly bridging into these constants.

Comment: thanks, Im guessing the strings map to the attributes, KSecClass etc, how did you find out what these attributes map to, eg "class", "genp", can I look these up somewhere?

Comment: I'm afraid I cheated and looked directly into their souls.

Answer (score 2):

The declaration of function is `func setObject(anObject: AnyObject!, forKey aKey: NSCopying!)`

where ,
**anObject** : A strong reference to the object is maintained by the dictionary. Raises an NSInvalidArgumentException if anObject is nil. If you need to represent a nil value in the dictionary, use NSNull.

**aKey** : The key for value. The key is copied (using copyWithZone:; keys must conform to the NSCopying protocol). Raises an NSInvalidArgumentException if aKey is nil. If aKey already exists in the dictionary anObject takes its place.

In your case **kSecClass** doesn't conforms to **NSCopying** protocol , therefore it is giving you Error.

Try using `returnDictionary = NSMutableDictionary(objects: [kSecClassGenericPassword], forKeys: [kSecClass])`

Also the below code should work [Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html)

```
var kSecClassSwift: NSString = kSecClass.takeRetainedValue() as NSString
returnDictionary.setObject(accessGroup, forKey: kSecClassSwift)
```

Due to the bug in Xcode 6 beta it is not working now , I hope in for the next release apple will fix it.

Comment: Give key which conforms to NSCopying , ex: "SecClass" is a string which conforms to NSCopying.

Comment: I want to use these to set a password in the keychain, I assumed that kSecClass should be passed in as key for kSecClassGenericPassword to KeyChain? is that not the case?

Comment: @Xerxes Try returnDictionary = NSMutableDictionary(objects: [kSecClassGenericPassword], forKeys: [kSecClass])

Comment: It works only for one element, But when I have to pass in a number of elements as I need to, it fails:
NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary(objects: [kSecClassGenericPassword, service, userAccount, dataFromString], forKeys: [kSecClass, kSecAttrService, kSecAttrAccount, kSecValueData])

Comment: Declare properly like :  var keyChain: NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary(objects: [kSecClassGenericPassword, service, userAccount,dataFromString], forKeys: [kSecClass, kSecAttrService, kSecAttrAccount, kSecValueData])

Comment: I'm surprised it worked. I tried the "returnDictionary" line exactly as @Yatheesha gave it, and we crashed at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Try using swift dictionary instead of objc dictionary, like from documentation

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/CollectionTypes.html